# How to use shortcuts sign out App Store on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, shortcut

I've recently become obsessed with automation
but I'm just a beginner with no foundation
Trying to learn iphone "shortcuts" app
Want to try on iphone with Scheme url
Make a one-click logout on the app store
Or switch appleid on iPhone app store
but all failed
Can't find ios app store "sign out" scheme url either

Currently only successful(The method is to open the url with the safari browser)

1.Jump to the subscription page with one click

```
itms-apps://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions
```

2.Jump to the account settings page with one click

```
itms-ui://
```

I tried changing the url
itms-apps://apps.apple.com/account
or
itms-apps://apps.apple.com/account/sign-out

all failed......

so i want to ask
Is it possible to log out of the app store appleid with one click?
Or is there any other way to achieve this
help me,please thanks

Comment: The shortcut what you are using is a deeplink which is meant to open a specific screen/page on an application and then the user will take the respective action. So logging out with click on deeplink/shortcut is not supported is what I believe also I think it's against the apple guideline.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I guessed the same.
In fact, I spent about 3 weeks looking for relevant information on this problem.
I haven't found an answer yet, so I'm asking.
There seems to be no other way to achieve "one-click logout",
Can only operate on its own